# get creation Date of spuser

Tags: spuser

I need to get all the users that are added to spgroup "XX" on specific date .

```
$url = "https://spsite.com
$User = Get-SPUser -web $url -Group "XX"

$User | Select Userlogin,Groups,DisplayName,Email,LoginName
```

how to get creation date ?

Comment: You mean when the user was first added to the site?

Comment: you will not get this for sure in above way. Adding user to the group will be logged in Audit log activity. may be you have to run a Powershell  against the audit log to find which user is added to which group on which date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the answer is to get users from the hide spList: "siteUserinfoList"

```
$today=Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"        
        $spSite = Get-SPSite $url 
        $spWeb = Get-SPWeb $url 
        $todayNewUsers =$spWeb.SiteUserInfoList.Items | ?{ (Get-date -Date $_['Created'] -UFormat "%m/%d/%Y") -eq $today}
```